# What happened to the Google Calculator? Does it still exists?

Tags: google-search, google-calculator

What happened to the Google Calculator? Does it still exist? I no longer see it.

Comment: You no longer see it *where*?

Comment: Google *is* a calculator - https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3284611?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

Google calculator will automatically show up and work when you search valid calculation syntax. eg. 2+2=

If it isn't appearing when you make a mathematical search, you may be entering your syntax invalidly. See https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3284611?hl=en for more details.

Were you talking about something else which you knew as Google Calculator, but which no longer exists?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

As October 28, 2016, it's still exists

## Exhibit 1

Taken from http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=calculator

[image: Google calculator]

## Troubleshooting

From the Google Search Help Center

> ### Calculator isn't appearing
>
> If the calculator doesn't show up when you enter in an equation:
>
> - Make sure your equation is something that can be computed. For example, if you search for 7*9/0, you won’t see the calculator pop up
>   because dividing by zero doesn’t create a value.
> - If it still isn't showing up, try adding = to the beginning or end of your search.

## References

[Calculator & unit converter - Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3284611?hl=en)

Answer (score -1):

Nothing happened to the Google Calculator.  It still exists.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit as to where it still exists.